# Randomization Display

Tags: javascript, math, if-statement, random, hex

I have a randomizer that gives me 6 different letters and 6 different numbers. This is going to, in the end, be used for a hex number.

I am trying to create a randomizer that will choose between the number or the letter for each slots of the hex (1-6).

I can create one that chooses in between them, but once it chooses, it doesn't know what they number to letter transition was

Example:

`if (mega === 1) {
    return "a";
}`

It does not remember that transition once inside of the letter/number chooser.

If anyone understands what I'm getting at, please help! Thank you. :)

//edit -- entire code
`

```
Variables Below Here

//Numbers
var ayy2 = Math.random() * 10;
var ayy = Math.floor(ayy2);

var lmd2 = Math.random() * 10;
var lmd = Math.floor(lmd2);

var qua2 = Math.random() * 10;
var qua = Math.floor(qua2);

var abc2 = Math.random() * 10;
var abc = Math.floor(abc2);

var cdf2 = Math.random() * 10;
var cdf = Math.floor(cdf2);

var lgt2 = Math.random() * 10;
var lgt = Math.floor(lgt2);

//Letters
var mega2 = Math.random() * 7;
var mega = Math.floor(mega2);

var nade2 = Math.random() * 7;
var nade = Math.floor(nade2);

var shot2 = Math.random() * 7;
var shot = Math.floor(shot2);

var suck2 = Math.random() * 7;
var suck = Math.floor(suck2);

var pepe2 = Math.random() * 7;
var pepe = Math.floor(pepe2);

var lols2 = Math.random() * 7;
var lols = Math.floor(lols2);

//Choices Between Hexes\\

var shrek2 = Math.random() * 3;
var shrek = Math.floor(shrek2);

var tpkek2 = Math.random() * 3;
var tpkek = Math.floor(tpkek2);

var waffl2 = Math.random() * 3;
var waffl = Math.floor(waffl2);

var snipe2 = Math.random() * 3;
var snipe = Math.floor(snipe2);

var optic2 = Math.random() * 3;
var optic = Math.floor(optic2);

var fazed2 = Math.random() * 3;
var faze = Math.floor(fazed2);

// Just for Dylan: ff88c6

//Functions Below Here\\

//Letter Returns

function returnLetter1() {
    if (mega === 1) {
        return "a";
    }
    if (mega === 2) {
        return "b";
    }
    if (mega === 3) {
        return "c";
    }
    if (mega === 4) {
        return "d";
    }
    if (mega === 5) {
        return "e";
    }
    if (mega === 6) {
        return "f";
    } else {
        return "f";
    }
}

function returnLetter2() {
    if (nade === 1) {
        return "a";
    }
    if (nade === 2) {
        return "b";
    }
    if (nade === 3) {
        return "c";
    }
    if (nade === 4) {
        return "d";
    }
    if (nade === 5) {
        return "e";
    }
    if (nade === 6) {
        return "f";
    } else {
        return "f";
    }
}

function returnLetter3() {
    if (shot === 1) {
        return "a";
    }
    if (shot === 2) {
        return "b";
    }
    if (shot === 3) {
        return "c";
    }
    if (shot === 4) {
        return "d";
    }
    if (shot === 5) {
        return "e";
    }
    if (shot === 6) {
        return "f";
    } else {
        return "f";
    }
}

function returnLetter4() {
    if (suck === 1) {
        return "a";
    }
    if (suck === 2) {
        return "b";
    }
    if (suck === 3) {
        return "c";
    }
    if (suck === 4) {
        return "d";
    }
    if (suck === 5) {
        return "e";
    }
    if (suck === 6) {
        return "f";
    } else {
        return "f";
    }
}

function returnLetter5() {
    if (pepe === 1) {
        return "a";
    }
    if (pepe === 2) {
        return "b";
    }
    if (pepe === 3) {
        return "c";
    }
    if (pepe === 4) {
        return "d";
    }
    if (pepe === 5) {
        return "e";
    }
    if (pepe === 6) {
        return "f";
    } else {
        return "f";
    }
}

function returnLetter6() {
    if (lols === 1) {
        return "a";
    }
    if (lols === 2) {
        return "b";
    }
    if (lols === 3) {
        return "c";
    }
    if (lols === 4) {
        return "d";
    }
    if (lols === 5) {
        return "e";
    }
    if (lols === 6) {
        return "f";
    } else {
        return "f";
    }
}

//Return Numbers

function returnNumber1() {
    var zz = qua;
    return zz;
}

function returnNumber2() {
    var mm = lmd;
    return mm;
}

function returnNumber3() {
    var hh = ayy;
    return hh;
}

function returnNumber4() {
    var jj = abc;
    return jj;
}

function returnNumber5() {
    var ww = cdf;
    return ww;
}

function returnNumber6() {
    var rr = lgt;
    return rr;
}

/*
This next little bit here is for my enjoyment and because it's necessary for the script. :P
*/

//Obviously, the above are to get a number of 1 or 2 (0 being else so 66/33% chances w/e) to find out if it will be a number or letter. 

//But, I can't find a way for the function below to show me what the hexes will be WITH the number>letter from the returnL's.

//Could it be that I possibly would have to move the mega === x below the hexchoices? sigh 

function returnHexChoice1() {
    if (shrek === 1) {
        return zz;
    } else {
        return mega;
    }
}

//Finals of the script display necessary.

//DID I WIN???????
function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) 
   {
       color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
   }
   return color;
}

function hex() {
    return "philosophy";
}
```

Comment: Please provide the entire code.

Comment: are to trying to make a random hex?

Comment: Yes, but while displaying all of the hex numbers/letters individually.

Comment: Just added it. @Kevin

Comment: Please go learn about arrays. Then you can come back with 1/10th as much code and we might be able to read it and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, you are pretty impressive with variable naming. I usually name mines "fart" or something like that. That is also because if you try to make use of constructs of a programming language, you will not need as many variables.

Before you ask any other questions, tou might want to check out a tutorial. If javascript is what is interesting you, try here : for example here : http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/. Learn about functions, arrays, etc.

1. For example, all your `returnLetterX()` are the same except they use a different value. Try making just one `returnLetter(value)` that uses `value` to know what to return. Also, instead of a long set of if/else statements on the same variable, you can use a switch. That's exactly what they're made for !
2. Then your `returnNumberX` functions don't do anything, except map from your names to the number. You might want to use arrays, so you have less names.
3. Finally, all your `rand()` calls at the start are repetitive as well. Combined with arrays, you can easily do this in a loop.

Your code then could look something like :

```
function letter(let)
{
    switch(let)
    {
        case 0: return 'a';
        case 1: return 'b';
        case 2: return 'c';
        case 3: return 'd';
        case 4: return 'e';
        case 5: return 'f';
    }

    // even better, use an array : 
    // var abcdef = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    // return abcdef[let];
}

function hexChoice(num, let, choice)
{
    if (choice == 0) // 0 for 33%, 1-2 for 67%
        return letter(let);
    else
        return num;
}

// this is not the best way to pick hex values !
for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    var number = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    var letter = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 ); // there are only 6 letters !
    var letnum = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 );

    var hex_digit = hexChoice(number, letter, letnum);
    // now do something with your hex digit... print it, add it to the "color" string ?
}
```

You can see it's much smaller, and much easier to read for a programmer.

**Once you understand all this code and you are capable to write something similar by yourself** you can wonder what *is* the best way to pick a a random hex digit, though it already is in the `getRandomColor` you copied from somewhere. Search the internet (this site, tutorials...) it is a question that is asked a lot already and does not need re-asking.

Comment: I am... beyond impressed. Thank you very much! I have been attempting to learn and play with Javascript for about a year or so and, as you can see, I'm trying my hardest. I am still in high school and being told I can do more and I try to learn so thank you very much for being so understanding and helpful! I will use that website (and your code!) for the future.

Also, this code means a lot! Thanks so much! :)